# Access class (or object) parent in a correct way using OOP

Tags: oop

I need know if this is inside the normal **OOP** behavior, or if not, what is the most common way to do it (without being specific to a language).

*I had a class instanced on the main, called **A** , which inside had instanced the class **B** as a variable. When **A** calls methods inside **B**, **B** needs some methods from **A** for work.*

For that, I must bypass the A reference itself via arguments or I must use always the tools specific for the language? **OOP** give some reference to this or it's out from their scope?

Thank you.

Comment: A class should not be dealing with instantiation of another classes. You should either inject a prepared instance of another class (aka Dependency Injection) or you could inject a factory. That's what the *Single-Responsibility Principle* is about

Comment: @djay Thanks you for the clue about the theme, is really interesting. If you want, can put an answer for vote up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I had a class instanced on the main, called A , which inside had
>   instanced the class B as a variable. When A calls methods inside B, B
>   needs some methods from A for work.

The problem here is that, your class A knows too much - it knows how to instantiate another class with its arguments, therefore it becomes also responsible for a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) responsibility. Thus you end up breaking the [Single-Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

So, let's take a look at your current class hierarchy

```
class A
{
    private b;

    public void A()
    {
         b = new B();
    }
}

a = new A();
```

Since you didn't inject an instance of `B`, this one also becomes bound to the class `A`.

- Since `B` is tightly-coupled to `A`, It makes unit-testing very very hard (because you cannot inject a mocked instance of `B`) i.e you cannot test class `A` in isolation
- It introduces another form of global state, since `B` comes from global scope

A proper way of doing this would be as (by adhering to the [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)):

```
class A
{
   private b;

   public void A(B bInstance)
   {
       b = bInstance;
   }
}

b = new B();
a = new A(b);
```